# getElementById in Firefox iframe returns null but works in Safari/Chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser, getelementbyid

I've two html files. One includes the other in an iframe. The iframe executes a getElementById on a previously created element. This works fine in Chrome/Safari but doesn't in Firefox/IE8, and I don't understand why.

Firefox returns: null

Safari returns: [object HTMLDivElement]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="comment.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**comment.html**

```
<div id="foobar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('foobar'));
</script>
```

Comment: What happens when you open comment.HTML directly?

Comment: Well, the same error appears. So I guess it's not really an iframe related issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comment html file is not properly formed. Try using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="foobar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('foobar'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works. I totally forgot that documents loaded in the iframe must be proper HTML documents (with doctype etc.). Thanks!